# Deploy Spring Cloud Function to OpenFaaS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, serverless, openfaas

Spring Cloud Function is a way to write serverless functions with Spring Boot. There are only adapters for AWS, Azure, etc. but no way to deploy to OpenFaaS yet.

How do I deploy a [Spring Cloud Function](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function) to [OpenFaaS](https://www.openfaas.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I created something using the official [Java11 template](https://github.com/openfaas/templates/tree/master/template/java11) but I am not sure if this is a good solution. You can find the code here: https://github.com/PySualk/spring-cloud-function-openfaas

Comment: I've managed to deploy your function on selfhosted openfaas. As we have now Spring Boot 3, with Spring Native based on Grall VM, do you think it could be possible to use it in this function?

Comment: Spring Boot 3 required Java 17 (https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0). I just checked and there is only the Java11 template in the official OpenFaas repo. Maybe OpenFaas is not the right solution if you want to work with Java... but I am not quite sure ;-)

Comment: I've forked your code and adapted it to Spring Boot 3 and Java 17: 
https://github.com/Marx2/spring-cloud-function-openfaas
It deploy & starts, but I have some problems with communication:
https://github.com/openfaas/faas/issues/1790